# Trying to create a variable with a node script that is located within a bash / shell script

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell, variables

I have a node script embedded within a bash script in a shell file called **node_in_bash.sh**. I am able to create a variable within the bash script and then use it in the node script, however I am having difficulties declaring a variable within the node script and then using it outside that node script (back in the bash script part of this file). Here is my **node_in_bash.sh** file

```
#!/bin/bash
bash_var="a variable created from bash"
# working
echo "bash_var = $bash_var" &&

node -e "
// working
console.log('using bash_var in node script... ' + '$bash_var')

var node_var='a variable created from node';
// working
console.log('node_var = ' + global.node_var);
// working
console.log('using node_var in node script... ' + global.node_var)
"
# not working
echo "using node_var in bash script... $node_var"
# not working
echo "node_var = $node_var"
```

the results of this look like this

```
using bash_var in node script... a variable created from bash
node_var = a variable created from node
using node_var in node script... a variable created from node
using node_var in bash script...
node_var =
```

I have tried a few different ways of calling for this variable but can't seem to figure out where I am messing it up.

Just to reiterate, I have to create the variable with the node script and then use it in Bash... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Try [zx](https://github.com/google/zx)

Comment: Note that you're **not** accessing the bash variable in the JavaScript code being run by Node. The variable's value has *already been subsituted* in the string you're asking Node.js to evaluate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, directly, not least because once the Node.js process has terminated, the variable doesn't exist anymore.

But what you *can* do is have Node.js output text that you capture in a Bash variable. For instance, this outputs `Result is: Hi there`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

RESULT=$(node -e "console.log('Hi there')");
echo "Result is:" $RESULT
```

This is just the same mechanism used for getting the text output of any other process, more about it in [this question's answers on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/how-can-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-shell-variable).